# Clicking on flask button runs python code and unpickles files with tokenizer

Tags: python, flask, tokenize

I am building a website with flask and when you click on a button I'm trying to run my machine learning code that is in a different .py file. But when I click on that button I get this error
**AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Tokenizer' on <module '__main__' from 'c:filepath'**
I've been told it's because my Tokenizer class isn't able to unpickle the file. But I'm not sure why it's not able to because when I run my machine learning code on it's own it works fine. But when I try to click on the button through flask, that's when I get that error. Any help would be much appreciated

The function I'm trying to run is called starter("no") from a file called Music_Generator_2.py

***app.py***

```
@app.route('/generated')
def generated():
    print("start")
    Music_Generator_2.start("no") #from Music_Generator_2
    print("sucess")
    return render_template('index.html', tested_generator="generated")
```

The error occurs on the second line of this code

***Music_Generator_2.py***

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model_25epochs.h5", custom_objects=SeqSelfAttention.get_custom_objects())
tokenizer = pickle.load(open("tokenizer25.p", "rb"))
#generate from random
max_generate = 200
unique_notes = tokenizer.unique_word
seq_len = 200
generate = generate_from_random(unique_notes, seq_len)
generate = generate_notes(generate, model, unique_notes, max_generate, seq_len)
write_midi_file(generate, tokenizer, "rand test.mid", start=seq_len - 1, fs=7, max_generate=max_generate)

#generate from a note
max_generate = 300
unique_notes = tokenizer.unique_word  # same as above
seq_len = 300
generate = generate_from_one_note(tokenizer, "72")
generate = generate_notes(generate, model, unique_notes, max_generate, seq_len)
```

This is the code that I'm trying to in my machine learning program

***Music_Generator_2.py***
Tokenizer class

```
class Tokenizer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.notes_to_index = {}
        self.index_to_notes = {}
        self.num_word = 0
        self.unique_word = 0
        self.note_freq = {}

    '''transform a list of notes from strings to indexes
        list_array is a list of notes in string format'''
    def transform(self, list_array):
        transformed = []
        for i in list_array:
            transformed.append([self.notes_to_index[note] for note in i])
        return np.array(transformed, dtype = np.int32)

    '''partial fir on the dictionary of the tokenizer
        notes is a list of notes'''
    def partial_fit(self, notes):
        for note in notes:
            note_str = ",".join(str(n) for n in note)
            if note_str in self.note_freq:
                self.note_freq[note_str] += 1
                self.num_word += 1
            else:
                self.note_freq[note_str] = 1
                self.unique_word += 1
                self.num_word += 1
                self.notes_to_index[note_str] =self.unique_word
                self.index_to_notes[self.unique_word] = note_str

    '''add a new note to the dictionary
        note is the new note to be added as a string'''
    def add_new_note(self, note):
        assert note not in self.notes_to_index
        self.unique_word += 1
        self.notes_to_index[note] = self.unique_word
        self.index_to_notes[self.unique_word] = note
```

**Solved: I moved my tokenizer class into it's own .py file and then I just imported that file for app.py and Mustic_Generator_2.py. I found the solution from [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/12738/)**

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue of how you are running Flask. Are you running it inside of a virtualenv? If so, make sure that the correct pip packages are installed. I would make sure that the environment in which I run Flask is identical to the one where you run it on your own and it works.

Comment: The flask app and the machine learning code are both in the same folder and both use the same virtualenv I believe